# Curious behaviour of BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...) construct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

**Background**

In recent work I attempted to use a construct of `BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...)` to create a column of results. The results were not what I expected. As a result, I investigated and came across some curious findings - set out below. Whilst I now know what works and what doesn't for this construct, I am not sure of the underlying reasons for this. Is anyone able to give an explanation for what I have found?

The original work had the following characteristics:

1. a series of consecutive worksheet rows were each associated with a spilled 1×n array of numeric values
2. the value of n increased by 1 in successive rows and was utilised within the spill formula for generating that row's array
3. the result of interest for each row was a single value obtained by wrapping the row's spill formula within the `SUM()` function.

When calculating each row's value using a formula for a single cell there was no problem.

The difficulties arose when attempting to exploit the characteristics of n to deliver a column of results using a `BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...)` construct in which

- the `SEQUENCE()` function generated the successive values of n and
- the `LAMBDA()` (used as the second argument of `BYROW()`) recreated the spill formula used to generate the 1×n array and its summation to a single value.

**Findings of Investigation**

1. One source of difficulty may be the differing value of n in the spilled 1×n arrays
2. Not every solution involving constant sized arrays produced the correct result: a solution involving `MAKEARRAY()` gave the correct result whilst one involving `EXPAND()` gave incorrect results
3. Replacing the `SEQUENCE()` argument in `BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...)`with a reference to a worksheet range produced correct results, even when that worksheet range was itself generated by the same `SEQUENCE()` used in the `BYROW()`
4. Attempting to use `LET(seq,SEQUENCE(...),BYROW(seq,...))` made no difference.
5. No solution was found to work if it contained two occurrences of `SEQUENCE()` within it.

**Details of Investigation**

[image: Screenshot of investigative work]

The investigation is based on a simplified version of the original work. It retains the characteristics of the original and, importantly, reproduces the difficulties found in that work.

The top half of the screenshot, range `A1:H8`, provides the data used. The "Number" column provides the values called n in the Background section. The remaining columns in the top half, labelled "SEQUENCE(1,Number,1+Number/10,1)" provide the spilled 1×n arrays. The formula for cell `B2` is

`=SEQUENCE(1,A2,1+A2/10,1)`

and this is copied to range `B3:B7`.

***Note:*** Use of `SEQUENCE()` to generate the 1×n arrays leads, in several of the attempted solutions to this function being used twice: first, as the first argument of `BYROW()`; and, second, within the `LAMBDA()` used as the second argument of `BYROW()`. The issue raised in this question is primarily about the first of these two uses.

The bottom half of the screenshot provides the correct results in column "Sum" and shows 7 different attempts to reproduce these results using a spilled array formula (in columns "Try1A" to "Try3C").

The formula for cell `A11` is

`=SUM(SEQUENCE(1,A2,1+A2/10,1))`

and this is copied to range `A12:A17`.

The formulas in cells `A11:A17` make no reference to any of the spilled arrays in the top half of the screenshot. Range `B2:H8` can be deleted entirely without affecting the results in the bottom half. Columns `B:H` in the top half are provided only for illustration and to help understand which results in the bottom half are correct and incorrect.

The initial attempt at using a spilled formula is shown in column "Try1A". The formula in cell`B11` is

`=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`

This does not produce the expected results (ie those in column "Sum"). Instead it reproduces the values in range `B2:B7`, the first column obtained when all 7 of the 1×n arrays are "stacked" leftwards and vertically.

Suspecting that it might be the variable sizes of the spilled arrays within the `LAMBDA()` of "Try1A", "Try2A" used `MAKEARRAY()` to generate constant sized arrays of size 1×7. The formula in cell `E11` is:

`=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(MAKEARRAY(1,7,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c>d,0,c+d/10))))))`

This worked and delivered the correct results.

Encouraged by this "Try3A" also generated 1×7 arrays but this time using `EXPAND()`. The formula in cell `F11` is

`=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0))))`

but this delivered the same incorrect result as "Try1A".

Finally, two variants of the incorrect formulas used in "Try1A" and "Try3A" were tested. In the first variant, the first argument of the `BYROW()` function was replaced with `A2:A8` resulting in formulas of:

"Try1B" cell `C11`: `=BYROW(A2:A8,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`
"Try3B" cell `G11`: `=BYROW(A2:A8,LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0))))`

Both worked and continued to work when range `A2:A8` was itself created using the spill formula of

`=SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1)` in cell `A2`

and the references to `A2:A8` replaced by the spill version of `A2#`

"Try1C" and "Try3C" built on the first variant by using the `LET()` function to replace direct references to the worksheet. The resulting formulas are:

"Try1C" cell `D11`: `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),BYROW(seq,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1)))))`
"Try3C" cell `H11`: `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),BYROW(seq,LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0)))))`

However, both delivered the same incorrect result as "Try1A".

To repeat from the start of this long question:

Whilst I now know what works and what doesn't for this construct of `BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...)`, I am not sure of the underlying reasons for this. Is anyone able to give an explanation for what I have found?

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is, but I'm unsure why you're using byrow in combination of sequence. Sequence works by row (or column, or both) already: `=SEQUENCE(7,,1.1,0.1)` for Try1A. If you're trying to get a 2D spill using byrow, than that's not possible; BYROW results in a single cell result per row of the range/array taking in. If you need a 2D result you need to check REDUCE or MAKEARRAY.It's unclear to me what your end goal is from this question.

Comment: Maybe this is what you mean? `=MAKEARRAY(7,7,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r<c,"",r+c/10)))`
Or using Reduce: `=DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(7),LAMBDA(a,b,IFERROR(VSTACK(a,b+SEQUENCE(,b)/10),""))),1)`

Comment: @P.b, I had hoped that my goal in posing this question was quite clear. I used a formula involving `=BYROW(SEQUENCE(...),...) to calculate a column of results and "the results were not what I expected. As a result, I investigated and came across some curious findings - set out [in the question]. Whilst I now know what works and what doesn't for this construct, I am not sure of the underlying reasons for this. Is anyone able to give an explanation for what I have found?"

Comment: @P.b, the specific goal was to calculate the 7×1 column of values current listed in the "Sum" column, but using a single spill formula rather than individual formulas for calculating each cell. This is spelt out in the text "_The bottom half of the screenshot provides the correct results in column "Sum" and shows 7 different attempts to reproduce these results using a spilled array formula (in columns "Try1A" to "Try3C")._" This text is in the section headed "Details of Investigation". I am not trying to find simplified versions of the column "Try1A"  or any of the other 6 "Try" columns...

Comment: ...I also appreciate that I cannot use BYROW() to generate a 2D spill. That is not what I am trying to do. (As noted earlier I am trying to generate a single column of 7 results). The LAMBDAs all return a single value by wrapping the 1×n or 1×7 arrays (depending on the specific "Try") that they generate within a `SUM`. The formulas used are all provided in the question, so this aspect should be clear.

Comment: The byrow does calculate in arrays, but only shows the first instance of the array per row. That explains the sum being the sum of the underlying values of that rows array. Byrow cannot spill to the right.

Comment: @P.b...yes, I agree with that comment. However, as Try2A, Try1B and Try3B show it is possible to generate the required spill array, within the `LAMBDA` and then `SUM` the elements of that array (still within the `LAMBDA`) and return that single value back to the `BYROW`. However, as the other Try's show this doesn't always happen and, instead, the `LAMBDA` returns the the first element of the generated array, despite the use of the `SUM` function. It is the inconsistency of the functional behaviour that I am seeking an explanation of, but so far without success.

Comment: Check this `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7),MAP(seq,LAMBDA(s,CHOOSECOLS(SEQUENCE(,s),s))))` and replace `MAP` with `BYROW`. This will work for your tries as well. Than it uses the logic per your intent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255073/discussion-between-dmm-and-p-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BYROW` function applies a `LAMBDA` function to **each row** of a given array or range. As such, each iteration is referencing an entire row, even if the array only contains a single column.

When using `=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7), LAMBDA(r, ...))`, the `SEQUENCE(7)` function returns an **array object** consisting of {1;2;3;4;5;6;7}. While you might expect the **r** variable to return a single numeric value from 1 to 7 for each row in the array, it actually returns another array object consisting of a single value from {1} to {7}. When the resulting array is then passed to either the *rows* or *columns* argument of the subsequent `SEQUENCE` function, Excel interprets this as an attempt to generate an array of arrays (a separate set of results for each value in the array), which is currently not supported. As such, only the first result will be returned. For example, `SEQUENCE(1, {5})` will only return 1.

When using `=BYROW(A2#, LAMBDA(r, ...))`, where cell `A2` contains the formula `=SEQUENCE(7)`, the correct results are returned because `A2#` is a **range object** referring to a single column that exists in the worksheet. Each row in the range contains a single cell only; and, when a single cell is referenced, its value is returned (ie: 5 instead of {5}).

Alternatively, the `MAP` function applies a `LAMBDA` function to **each value** of a given array. When using `=MAP(SEQUENCE(7), LAMBDA(n, ...))`, the **n** variable does in fact return a single numeric value from 1 to 7, because it processes each item in the array individually. This is why the `MAP` function can be a better option than `BYROW` or `BYCOL` when working with 1D arrays.

Having said that, there are ways of overcoming the described issue with `BYROW` when working with a single column array. The `INDEX` function, as well as the implicit intersection operator `@`, can be used to reference the first item in each row and return a single value. For example, the **Try1A** formula mentioned in the OP can be modified to work as follows:

```
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7), LAMBDA(r, LET(n, INDEX(r, 1), SUM(SEQUENCE(, n, 1 + n / 10)))))
```

-OR-

```
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7), LAMBDA(r, SUM(SEQUENCE(, @r, 1 + @r / 10))))
```

**Note:** when using the implicit intersection operator method shown above, you may be prompted with the following message:

> This formula is not supported by some older versions of Excel.
>
> Would you like to use this variation instead?
>
> =@BYROW(SEQUENCE(7), LAMBDA(r, SUM(SEQUENCE(, @r, 1 + @r / 10))))

Click **No** to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `MAP` is a much better choice of function than `BYROW` in this situation.

The longer answer is that what are called "Try1A", "Try1B" and "Try1C" in the question have the following formulas associated with them:

Try1A: `=BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`
Try1B: `=BYROW(A2#,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`
Try1C: `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),BYROW(seq,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1)))))`

`A2#` is a spill generated by formula `=SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1)` in cell `A2`.

Unexpectedly, **these 3 formulas do not generate the the same result**. The question sought an explanation for this inconsistency.

After an extensive discussion, user **@P.b** made the suggestion that the `MAP` function should be used instead of `BYROW`. This yields the following formulas:

Try1A: `=MAP(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`
Try1B: `=MAP(A2#,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1))))`
Try1C: `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),MAP(seq,LAMBDA(d,SUM(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1)))))`

All three formulas yield the same results, namely the expected and correct results shown in the column labelled "Sum" in the image showing in the question.

Further, when the same substitution of `MAP` for `BYROW` is made in the remaining 4 "Try"'s of the question, the following formulas result:

Try2A: `=MAP(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(MAKEARRAY(1,7,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c>d,0,c+d/10))))))`
Try3A: `=MAP(SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0))))`
Try3B: `=MAP(A2#,LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0))))`
Try3C: `=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(7,1,1,1),MAP(seq,LAMBDA(d,SUM(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(1,d,1+d/10,1),1,7,0)))))`

and these 4 formulas again all produce the same correct result, whereas previously they had suffered from the same inconsistency problem displayed by the first 3 when using `BYROW`.

The reason why `BYROW` displays its inconsistency still remains a mystery. The only consistent element appears to be that using the function `SEQUENCE()` twice within the spill formula yields incorrect (ie not the expected) results, whilst using it only once yields correct (expected) results.

`MAP` does not suffer from this inconsistency and always delivers the correct results irrespective of precisely how the first argument of the `MAP` function and the second argument of the `MAP`'s `LAMBDA` are specified.

Comment: @P.b the original piece of work that motivated all this is [this question from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1805616)